# Oracle Linux 5: 21% received packet drop

Tags: ethernet, tcp, oracle-linux

This is what I'm seeing:

```
# netstat -i

Kernel Interface table
Iface       MTU Met    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
bond0      1500   0   703449      0 147463      0   978099      0      0      0 BMmRU
eth4       1500   0   306302      0      0      0   259244      0      0      0 BMsRU
eth5       1500   0   397147      0      6      0   718855      0      0      0 BMsRU
lo        16436   0  1977704      0      0      0  1977704      0      0      0 LRU


# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer3+4 (1)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 5000
Down Delay (ms): 5000

802.3ad info
LACP rate: fast
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
Active Aggregator Info:
       Aggregator ID: 1
       Number of ports: 2
       Actor Key: 17
       Partner Key: 32912
       Partner Mac Address: RE:DA:CT:ED:be:05

Slave Interface: eth4
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: RE:DA:CT:ED:1a:da
Aggregator ID: 1
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth5
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: RE:DA:CT:ED:1a:db
Aggregator ID: 1
Slave queue ID: 0
```

21% packet drop amounts to a DOS attack. (I'm not far enough along in my investigation to have an opinion on "deliberate" and/or "malicious.") The bond is comprised of `eth4` and `eth5`. No other interfaces are active on the host.

What this is not:

- No firewall is running on this host. This isn't packet drop due to an internal firewall.
- `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0` shows no errors
- `ethtool -S <iface>` shows no errors, but only has results for the individual interfaces; nothing on the bond as a whole.
- The Networking team says the switch is matching this host's IP address with the bond MAC address, and both values are correct.

Limitations:

- The network is run by a different team. I have no direct access to the switches.

Questions:

- What would cause the bond to drop packets?

  - Why is the bond showing packet drop, but not the individual interfaces?
- What Cisco switch suggestions can I pass back to the Networking team to help narrow this down?
- If I start a `tcpdump` on the bond, would it see the packets getting dropped, or does the drop happen before the point where `tcpdump` do its recording?
- I found a reference to [dropwatch](https://fedorahosted.org/dropwatch/), and installed and ran it. The only drops are of the form

  0 drops at irq_stack_union+0
  -1 drops at __per_cpu_end+fffee201
  -1 drops at __per_cpu_end+fffee202

Looking into that, now.

- [irqbalance](http://linux.die.net/man/1/irqbalance) shows a whole bunch of information, none of which is a slam dunk. But, the daemon is running on the host.

[This Red Hat solution](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/657483) mentions "Softnet Backup Full." Other solutions add "measured in `/proc/net/softnet_stat`". None of the solutions so far goes into detail on what that means. How do I specifically identify that "Softnet Backup Full" is or is not the source of these packet drops?

Comment: Might be better off asking on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be "works as designed." See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/657483